# From concurrent.futures to asyncio

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I have two problems with [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html):

## How to break time.sleep() in a python concurrent.futures?

Conclusion: time.sleep() cannot be interrupted. One solution is: You can write a loop around it and do short sleeps.

See [How to break time.sleep() in a python concurrent.futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461603/how-to-break-time-sleep-in-a-python-concurrent-futures)

## Individual timeouts for concurrent.futures?

Conclusion: individual timeouts need to implemented by the user. For example: for each timeout you  can call to [wait()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait).

See  [Individual timeouts for concurrent.futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456357/individual-timeouts-for-concurrent-futures)

## Question

Does [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) solve theses problems?

Comment: For the sake of self-containment, can you summarise those other two questions here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the asyncio model, execution is scheduled and coordinated by an event loop. To cancel execution of a currently suspended task, you essentially simply have to *not resume* it. While this works a little different in practice, it should be obvious that this makes cancelling a suspended task simple in theory.

Individual timeouts are certainly possible the same way: whenever you suspend a coroutine to wait for a result, you want to supply a timeout value. The event loop will ensure to cancel the waiting task when that timeout is reached and the task hasn't completed yet.

Some concrete samples:

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
>>> task = asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.sleep(5))
>>> task.cancel()
>>> loop.run_until_complete(task)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

In practice, this might be implemented using something like this:

```
class Foo:
    task = None

    async def sleeper(self):
        self.task = asyncio.sleep(60)
        try:
            await self.task
        except concurrent.futures.CancelledError:
            raise NotImplementedError
```

While this method is asleep, somebody else can call `foo.task.cancel()` to wake up the coroutine and let it handle the cancellation. Alternatively whoever calls `sleeper()` can cancel *it* directly without giving it a chance to clean up.

Setting timeouts is similarly easy:

```
>>> loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.sleep(60), 5))
[ ... 5 seconds later ... ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
```

Particularly in the context of HTTP request timeouts, see [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io):

```
async def fetch_page(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            assert response.status == 200
            return await response.read()

with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
    content = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_page(session, 'http://python.org'))
```

Obviously each call to `fetch_page` can decide on its own `aiohttp.Timeout` value, and each individual instance will throw its own exception when that timeout is reached.

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thank you. Imagine I use the subprocess module (I read that it is supported), then I want to terminate the subprocess somehow. Do you have a hint how to do this?

Comment: Not really, no. You should open a new question for that.

Comment: @guettli Have a look at the [asyncio.subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) module and those [examples](http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can raise immediately in its exception (with `asyncio.CancelledError`).

I use this method for the catch to overcome it:

```
import asyncio

async def worker():
    try:
        # await for some coroutine process
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        # Do stuff
        raise asyncio.CancelledError()
    except Exception as exc:
        # Do stuff
        print(exc)
    finally:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
```